# How do you use "as it causes"?

Tags: clauses

> The researchers concluded that glare slows down reading because people cannot properly view what is on the computer, as it causes them to take more time to try to figure out what they are reading.

Should I just break it up into two sentences or can I keep it as one?

Comment: ...*because it causes*...

Comment: As can be used rather than because.  That just a style choice.

Comment: It's also about avoiding repetition, as the writer has already used "because" in the sentence.  However, they are not always interchangeable.  "As" introduces a reason or justification for the preceding statement, whereas "because" introduces the cause of the preceding statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider three sentences:

> The researchers concluded that glare slows down reading.  People cannot properly view what is on the computer.  It causes them to take more time to try to figure out what they are reading.

This may seem less structured but now it can be read slowly, and powerfully.